# Checking for alarm by PendingIntent always returns null, but alarm is set

Tags: android

I'm setting an alarm to run a service every 2 minutes.  I'm also checking elsewhere to see if that alarm is currently set.  However, my check for the alarm always returns false (that it is NOT set), but if I put a breakpoint in the service, sure enough, within 2 minutes, it hits it.  So, the alarm IS set, but I can't tell.

Here is the code I use to set the alarm:

```
public void setWakeUpFromNow(long millisecFromNow) {
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnWakeUpReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis() + millisecFromNow, pIntent);

 }
```

And here is where I check to see if it is set

```
 public boolean isWakeUpSet() {
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnWakeUpReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);   

    return pIntent != null;
 }
```

isWakeUpSet always returns false, even though the OnWakeUpReceiver later gets woken up.